GitHub API: 409 Conflict When Adding or Updating Repository Content
I'm using the GitHub API to create a repository and then add content to it. The repository creation works fine, but when I try to update content in the repository, I get a 409 Conflict status code.
Here’s the code I’m using to create the repository:
await octokit.request('POST /user/repos', { 
name: 'Hello-World', 
description: 'This is your first repo!', 
homepage: 'https://github.com', 
private: false, 
is_template: true, 
headers: { 'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28' } 
});

To add or update content in the repository, I’m using the following API:
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}

GITHUB API CONTENT ADD AND UPDATE DOCS HERE.
However, when I make the request to update a file, I receive a 409 Conflict error.
Here is only question found on stackoverflow related to conflict here.
How can I resolve this conflict and successfully commit the new content, possibly replacing the existing file contents?

What URL are you using to update the file?  You really havn't given us much detail.

Hey thanks of your comment  I resolved it by getting the latest sha for the specific file and added the sha in update api body.
